# How do you promote blogs to a page other than the home page in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I really like the promote to home page feature of drupal. But what if I want some content promoted to a page other than the home page. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "promote to front page" is a helper that puts the page in the /node URL. If your front page is not /node, the "promote to front page" won't really do what you expect.

If you want a list of nodes, then views will do the trick. However, if what you want is to put a node in a page that is another node as if it was a block, then I suggest you look at the "node as block" module.

From the module description:
This module allows those with the appropriate permissions the right to create blocks for each node. By default these blocks display the node title as the block title and the node teaser as the body.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Views for this purpose.  For instance, create a taxonomy vocabulary with terms corresponding to the various pages you might want content to be promoted to.  Then create or edit that content and tag it accordingly.  In Views, use the taxonomy filter to display only the matching content.

Answer (score 0):

As often, there are many ways to do that. The Flag module is a good way to put all kinds of markers on nodes. Another option is the Nodequeue module. This module allows the content creator to group nodes in 'queues' and control the order.